# Having trouble passing Jenkins variables into Windows Powershell build step

Tags: powershell, plugins, jenkins

I cannot get variables to pass into a Windows Powershell build step in Jenkins.  I've tried:

```
$env:JENKINS_HOME
${JENKINS_HOME}
```

And I still cannot get it to work.  As a test, I tried:

```
$JENKINS_HOME=$env:JENKINS_HOME
Write-Host 'This is $JENKINS_HOME'
```

and the output is simply `This is $JENKINS_HOME`.  What gives?

Comment: If you use single quotes, `write-host` will output the literal string. You need to use double quotes `write-host "this is $JENKINS_HOME"` to interpolate variables

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work.  However, it doesn't look like the powershell plugin shows the script running like in the ISE....so there's no console equivalent.